# Trim a url to just the domain name using PHP

Tags: php

I have a database table column that stores urls of a persons website. This column is unique as I don't want people using the same website twice!

However a person could get around this by doing:

```
domain.com
domain.com/hello123
www.domain.com
```

So my plan is to make it so that when a person saves their record it will remove everything after the first slash to make sure only the domain is saved into the database.

How would I do this though? I'm presuming this has been done lots of times before, but I'm looking for something VERY VERY simple and not interested in using libraries or other long code snippets. Just something that strips out the rest and keeps just the domain name.

Comment: Not sure I get your point. Doesn't the resulting URL need to point to the original site?

Comment: No sorry I should of mentioned that. I just want the site domain. So for example if a user posts: `http://www.domain.com/hello/how/are/you` I want to save `http://www.domain.com/` in the DB.

Comment: Is it really unacceptable to have a website on the same domain as someone else?  What if "their website" is a blog or a facebook page or a stackoverflow user page.  Just something to think about, I don't know your exact requirements.

Comment: In this instance yes it's important that domains are unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [parse_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$hostname = parse_url($userwebsite,PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Comment: This will return NULL for all three given examples (PHP 5.3.10 on Kubuntu 12.04).

Comment: URL must be pre-checked, of course. Or just check if `$hostname` is `NULL` or `FALSE` and return error.

Answer (score 5):

See [PHP: parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
// Force URL to begin with "http://" or "https://" so 'parse_url' works
$url = preg_replace('/^(?!https?:\/\/)(.*:\/\/)/i', 'http://', $inputURL);
$parts = parse_url($url);
// var_dump($parts); // To see the parsed URL parts, uncomment this line
print $parts['host'];
```

Note, the subdomains are not unique using the code as listed. `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` will be separate entries.

Comment: `parse_url()` should only be called on complete URI. `var_dump(parse_url('www.example.org'))` will return "path" and not "host".

Comment: Thanks @Shi for pointing that out. I added some regex to force a HTTP(S) scheme.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sDomain = NULL;

foreach (explode('/', $sInput) as $sPart) {
  switch ($sPart) {
    case 'http:':
    case 'https:':
    case '':
      break;

    default:
      $sDomain = $sPart;
      break 2;
  }
}

if ($sDomain !== NULL) {
  echo $sDomain;
}
```

First, all slashes are used as separators. Next, all "known/supported" schemes are ignored, as well as the empty part which happens from "http://". Finally, whatever is next will be stored in `$sDomain`.

If you do not mind the dependency of PCRE, you can use a regular expression as well:

```
if (preg_match('/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)/', $sInput, $aisMatch) === 1) {
  echo $aisMatch[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
int strrpos ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

and then put the result of that into

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

using `$needle = "/"` and `$needle = "."`